# NestJS dependency injection during unit test

Tags: dependency-injection, jestjs, nestjs

I am stuck with the dependency injection problem of NestJS during the unit test with jest. Here is my codebase. `app.controller.spec.ts`

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

describe('AppController', () => {
  let appController: AppController;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const app: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [AppController],
      providers: [AppService],
    }).compile();

    appController = app.get<AppController>(AppController);
  });

  describe('root', () => {
    it('should return "Hello World!"', () => {
      expect(appController.getHello()).toBe('Hello World!');
    });
  });
});
```

The problem is, there is dependency injection in `app.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable, CACHE_MANAGER, Inject } from "@nestjs/common";
import {Cache} from "cache-manager";

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
    constructor(@Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cacheManager: Cache) {}

    getHello(): string {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

In general, nest automatically performs dependency injection during bootup, but this isn't happening while running unit-test and giving me the following error:

`Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AppService (?). Please make sure that the argument CACHE_MANAGER at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context.`

Any idea how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: you didn't provide any value to the provider token `CACHE_MANAGER`. See examples on this topic here: https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs

Comment: I know right, I'm just not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add the `CACHE_MANAGER` as a provider to your TestingModule:

```js
const app: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService,
    { provide: CACHE_MANAGER, useFactory: jest.fn() },
  ],
}).compile();
```